# android app very slow on real device

Tags: java, android

(Im using android studio)
the problem is when i run my app on a real device it is so slow, instead on emulator it is quite fast, i saw that i have to extend asynctask on my class or create a new thread in the slowest parts of code, but im new and i don't know how to do it, i tried to create new threads when user hits the buttons, but it didnt work, so if someone can help i will appreciate it.
this is only the main activity because id like just to know how to do it, and i will change other classes after understanding.

by the way, on xml file i have 3 buttons, 1 listview, 1 textview.

```
package com.wog.playerslist;

import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.content.DialogInterface;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.AdapterView;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String itemName;
int itemPosition;
ArrayList<String> player = new ArrayList<>(4);
ArrayList<String> playersList = new ArrayList<>(50);
ArrayAdapter<String> playersAdapter;
ListView playersListView = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    playersListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewPlayers);
    playersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new 
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            setItemName(playersListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            setItemPosition(position);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

public void onButtonAddClicked(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayerAddActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null)
        setIntent(intent);
    Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        if (extras.getString("Edit") != null) {
            playersList.remove(itemPosition);
            playersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        String player;
        player = extras.getString("Nick") + " - " + extras.getString("Tag") + " - " + extras.getString("Vic") + " - " + extras.getString("Def");
        playersList.add(player);
        playersAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, playersList);
        playersListView.setAdapter(playersAdapter);
        playersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public void onRemoveBtnClicked(View view) {
    if (itemName != null) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Delete");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Delete " + itemName + "?");
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                playersList.remove(itemPosition);
                playersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                itemName = null;
                itemPosition = -1;
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please, select a player!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}

public void setItemName(String str) {
    this.itemName = str;
}

public void setItemPosition(int i) {
    this.itemPosition = i;
}

public void onEditButtonClicked(View view) {

    int i;
    int x = 0;
    int add = 0;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayerAddActivity.class);
    if (itemName != null) {
        while (add <= 2) {
            i = itemName.indexOf(" - ", x);
            player.add(add, itemName.substring(x, i));
            x = i + 3;
            add++;
        }
        player.add(add, itemName.substring(x, itemName.length()));

        intent.putExtra("Edit", "editView");
        intent.putExtra("Nick", player.get(0));
        intent.putExtra("Tag", player.get(1));
        intent.putExtra("Vic", player.get(2));
        intent.putExtra("Def", player.get(3));
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please, select a player!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

By design the new Android Emulator is faster in most cases than a physical Android device. Slowness can also depend on the type of phone you are using, external libraries, and most importantly your coding technique. Check out this youtube link for more info https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fs0eira2pRY&feature=youtu.be&t=27m42s

Comment: i think its my coding technique, for this reason i have attached my code